# How to start a new Xsession for SSH forwarding?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, x11-forwarding, remote-x-session

I want to forward an Xsession over ssh to another system, but I get this error:

```
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
    and start again.
```

I don't want to kill the currently running Xsession. How can I start a new Xsession for ssh forwarding?

Running Ubuntu 12.04 on both client and server.

Comment: You used to be able to drop to a command line and run startx :1 to start a second session.

Comment: @Mordoc, I found I can start a new xsession over ssh using `startx -- :1`, though I still couldn't figure out how to forward GUI applications.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative solution to your problem, you can reuse the existing display :0 for running applications.

```
DISPLAY=:0 ssh -X username@192.168.0.100
```

Source:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=8455